# Rewrite request URI based on Host header in HAProxy

Tags: haproxy, rewrite

I would like to set up HAProxy to forward HTTP requests to some backend servers but I need it to also rewrite the URI part based on the Host. I've read through the doc but it seems that ***reqirep*** isn't suitable for this purpose. Any idea if this is even possible with HAProxy?

Here are the details of what I'm trying to accomplish:

Requests that come in on:

```
http://www.original-domain.com/
```

would be balanced between:

```
http://server1/domains/www.original-domain.com/
...
http://serverN/domains/www.original-domain.com/
```

The proxy should be able to handle this for any number of domains (original-domain.com can be anything, it's not limited to a fixed set of values).

For this to work HAProxy would need to rewrite a request like this:

```
GET /original-uri HTTP/1.1
Host: original-domain.com
```

to:

```
GET /domains/original-domain.com/original-uri HTTP/1.1
Host: serverN
```

and forward that request to one of the internal servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Willy Tarreau, HAProxy's creator, answered my question on the HAProxy mailing list.

> No, we still can't do that. We have to
>   implement a mechanism to extract parts
>   of requests and reuse them at other
>   places (basically session-based
>   variables) but there's nothing yet.
>   It's in the roadmap though.
>
> You'll have to find another way to do
>   it unfortunately. If you have just a
>   few domains, you can write a few rules
>   (one per domain) to perform
>   conditional rewrites (eg: if Host
>   matches XX, rewrite URI as
>   /domains/XX/original-uri).
>
> If you have too many of them, you'd
>   better look at another product for the
>   job. I think that nginx is
>   particularly suited at these tasks.
>
> Regards, Willy

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt to do this using the "redirect" option in HAProxy.

```
redirect prefix http://server1/domains/
```

However, it is a redirect, so it will not be transparent.

I do not believe HAProxy can rewrite URLs transparently (on their way to the backend servers).

Comment: Redirecting could probably set up to be transparent and it might work if I would be able to extract the original host name and append it to the prefix but it doesn't seem that's possible either.